# specify different delay/duration in jquery animations?

Tags: jquery, animation

When doing multiple animations simultaneously on the same element, how can I specify different durations and delay times for both?

For example, if I want to make a div grow, and fade it out in the second half of the growth, I would do

```
mydiv.animate({width:450,height:250},1000); 
mydiv.delay(500).animate({opacity:0},500);
```

however, these are executed sequentially, not simultaneously. How can I get the desired effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/qopudu/2/edit?html,css,js,output)**

Simply set `queue: false` for the first animation set.

```
mydiv.animate({
   width: 450,
   height:250
}, { duration: 1000, queue: false });

mydiv.delay(500).animate({
   opacity:0
}, { duration: 500});
```

Comment: That is definitely looks like it's the intended way. Thanks!

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef :) :) happy coding to you too!